# How to change sum headers in group_by of a tree view into min?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I need to remove the sum header of some columns that it automatically calculated for me.

I created a new tree view without inheriting any view, and have the fields like so:

```
. . .
<field name="model">my.purchase.order.line.inherit</field>
. . .
  . . .
  <field name="product_uom_qty"/>
  <field name="price_unit"/>
  . . .
  <field name="price_subtotal" widget="monetary"/>
  . . .
. . .
```

[image: Column Sum]

The main model is from `purchase.order.line`.

Now with the answer from CZoellner, my model is now something like this.

```
class purchase_order_line_inherit(models.Model):
    _name = "my.purchase.order.line.inherit"
    _inherit = "purchase.order.line"

    product_uom_qty = fields.Float(group_operator="min")
```

I think the system just calculated them for me but the point is that I want to change it from **sum** to **min**.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398260/how-to-remove-hide-total-sum-in-tree-view-in-odoo) but my fields (as shown earlier) do not have the sum attribute. I also have tried something like [this](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/group-by-zero-count-in-tree-view-126813) but the sum headers are still there.

How can I achieve such task?

Comment: mostly, you need to create a new model specifically for the report

Comment: found it:

`def read_group(self, domain, fields, groupby, offset=0, limit=None, orderby=False, lazy=True)`

override method to modify the sum results..
search for other examples of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that solves this problem for me as recommended by many people.

You need to inherit `read_group` method and give it the value you want to display in the header column for the fields you want to customize.

This is the starter template of where to begin. [Reference](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-show-sum-total-for-a-compute-field-in-list-view-group-by-153745?forum=forum.forum%281%2C%29&question=forum.post%28153745%2C%29)

```
class your_class(models.Model):
    # ...        
    @api.model 
    def read_group(self, domain, fields, groupby, offset=0, limit=None, orderby=False, lazy=True):
        res = super(your_class, self).read_group(domain, fields, groupby, offset=offset, limit=limit, orderby=orderby, lazy=lazy)
        if 'invoice_due_local_currency' in fields:
            for line in res:
                if '__domain' in line:
                    lines = self.search(line['__domain'])
                    total_invoice_due = 0.0
                    for record in lines:
                        total_invoice_due += record.invoice_due_local_currency
                    line['invoice_due_local_currency'] = total_invoice_due

        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define that on field definition. In your case it would be:

```py
my_field = fields.Float(compute="_compute_my_field", group_operator="min")
```

The possible operators can be found in [the documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#fields).

> group_operator (str) – aggregate function used by read_group() when
> grouping on this field.
>
> Supported aggregate functions are:
>
> array_agg : values, including nulls, concatenated into an array
>
> count : number of rows
>
> count_distinct : number of distinct rows
>
> bool_and : true if all values are true, otherwise false
>
> bool_or : true if at least one value is true, otherwise false
>
> max : maximum value of all values
>
> min : minimum value of all values
>
> avg : the average (arithmetic mean) of all values
>
> sum : sum of all values

Comment: I tried this method, but it does not work. The sum header is still there and sum the values instead of using min. It looks like nothing happened to the field. I also have to add that the model I am using is from "purchase.order.line", not my own.

Comment: Could you add your "new" code to your question? It's difficult to understand what exactly was done by you.

Comment: Just remove the `_name` line, because you're creating a new model instead of extenting/changing one by having different `_inherit` and `_name` values.

Comment: But I do not want to extend the purchase.order.line model because there are multiple views that are using the model with the correct sum header as it is. Therefore, I want to change just the sum header in this view only, without anything affecting other views that are using this particular model. That is why I intended to create a new one.

Comment: Ah okay, then my solution isn't the one you need.

Comment: Then you probably have to override `read_group()` and switch the operator depending of a context flag or something. Not that easy i guess.

Comment: I have my custom action window ready for any changes from that component, but I don't know how to do the `read_group()` thing.

Comment: Sorry that would be too much to write down. Overriding that method isn't so easy.